# Align text in an inline-block section

Tags: position, css

I'm trying to create a chat website. I've created 3 frames (message, userlist, compose). But I have 3 problems with my layout (inline-block).

You can see my problems here: [image]

I'm trying to:

1. put all messages on the bottom of the frame
2. align messagebox and userlist (I don't understand why the frame "contactbox" isn't on top of the container)
3. remove the free space between the two box on top and the compose box. (I don't understand from where comes the free space here)

I would like to stick with the inline-block method, if it is possible.

HTML:

```
<section id="mainframe">
    <article id="messagebox">
        <p class="send">Message envoyé</p>
        <p class="received">Message reçu</p>
        <p class="send">Message envoyé</p>
        <p class="received">Message reçu</p>
    </article><!--
    --><aside id="contactbox">
        <p>Contact1</p>
        <p>Contact2</p>
        <p>Contact3</p>
    </aside><!--
    --><aside id="composebox">
        <p>Je taperai mon message ici !</p>
    </aside>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#mainframe{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid white;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#mainframe p{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    //border: 1px solid #009999;
}

#mainframe #messagebox{
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 85%;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    height: 500px;
}

#mainframe #contactbox{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15%;
    // vertical-align: top;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: right;
}

#mainframe #composebox{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking at [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)?

Comment: flexbox or even display:table&Cie can do that job : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bpkxr this could be the answer, say so if it does